# Why is the page header not saved when I save and close a workbook?

Tags: excel, vba, office365, worksheet

Using a macro, I have a workbook that I want to open if not already open, add/modify the page header, then save when closing it.

Everything appears to work until the save and close part.  The page header is there when I check right before saving the workbook.  After closing and saving changes, I open the workbook tgo find the header is missing.

I use a network drive so I tried using the C: drive instead just in case it was a network issue (an extreme long shot but I'm searching for any cause).
I tried saving the workbook, re-opening it, changing the page header and then re-saving it.
I've tried renaming the workbook when saving.
I do need to use a variable for the header since it will be changing when I run it. I set it to "Saturday" here in order to keep the code as simple as necessary.

Each time the header would disappear when I re-open the workbook. This all works if I do it manually, but not when using a macro to do it.

```
    Option Explicit
    Sub Header_Test()

    Dim WB As Workbook
    Dim wPathName, wBookName, wExt, wFullPathName As String
    Dim LHeader As String
    
    wPathName = "C:\Temp\"
    wBookName = "Header Test"
    wExt = ".xlsx"
    wFullPathName = wPathName & wBookName & wExt
    LHeader = "Saturday"
    
    'Open workbook (if not open) and make it active.
    For Each WB In Workbooks
        If WB.Name = wBookName Then 'If Header Test workbook is open then make it active.
            WB.Activate
        Else
            Workbooks.Open (wFullPathName) 'Workbook isn't open so open it.
        End If
    Next WB
    
    'Add left header.
    Application.PrintCommunication = False
    With Sheets("Sheet1").PageSetup
        .LeftHeader = "&24 " & LHeader
        .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
        .Orientation = xlPortrait
        .PaperSize = xlPaperLetter
        .FitToPagesWide = 1
        .FitToPagesTall = 1
        .PrintErrors = xlPrintErrorsDisplayed
    End With
    
    'Save and close
    Workbooks(wBookName).Close savechanges:=True
    
    End Sub
```

Comment: There's a much better way to test if the workbook is already open. Your current attempt could easily call `Workbooks.Open` multiple times, even though the workbook is already open.

Comment: Side note: `Workbooks.Open` returns a reference to the newly opened workbook. So instead of `Workbooks.Open (wFullPathName)`, use something like `Dim myWB As Workbook`, `Set myWB = Workbooks.Open(wFullPathname)`. Then refer to `myWB`, not `Workbooks(wBookName)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if the header is the correct way you wanted but here's the result on my end with the edited code:

```
Sub Header_Test()
    Dim WB As Workbook, LHeader As String
    Dim wPathName, wBookName, wExt, wFullPathName As String
    
    wPathName = "Q:\Aankoop\Werkfiles Excel\Steven\Test\"
    wBookName = "Header Test"
    wExt = ".xlsx"
    wFullPathName = wPathName & wBookName & wExt
    LHeader = "Saturday"
    
    'Open workbook (if not open) and make it active.
    Set WB = Workbooks.Open(wFullPathName)
    'WB.Activate
    'Add left header.
    Application.PrintCommunication = False
    With WB.Sheets("Sheet1").PageSetup
        .LeftHeader = "&24 " & LHeader
        .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
        .Orientation = xlPortrait
        .PaperSize = xlPaperLetter
        .FitToPagesWide = 1
        .FitToPagesTall = 1
        .PrintErrors = xlPrintErrorsDisplayed
    End With
    Application.PrintCommunication = True 'See (Edit:) below code
    'Save and close
    WB.Save
    WB.Close

End Sub
```

(Didn't see BigBen's last comment on your question so this is a bit redundant) I didn't understand why you didn't just use `Workbooks.Open(wFullPathName)` to be honest, it's the easiest way to make sure that when the filepath exists, that it's opened because it doesn't care that it's already opened.
The `WB.Activate` I felt was unnecessary as well as long as you fully declare the sheet, i.e. `WB.Sheets("Sheet1")`
Last pointer, why use `Workbooks(wBookName).Close` when you already have a workbook variable `WB`?

(Edit:) Can't really call this an edit since I haven't posted my answer yet but I started testing a bit more and stumbled upon your same issue @OP. The code worked when going step by step through the code, running it with F5 however, didn't change the file even when I tried changing a range and changing it back to original value after a save and then saving again. Nor did `Application.Wait` help. Then I looked at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.printcommunication) and noticed them using `Application.PrintCommunication = True` for the following
***Set the PrintCommunication property to True after setting properties to commit all cached PageSetup commands.***
Before you ask, I have no idea why going step by step does this automatically and when running a code you need the extra line..

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- I've tested the code on M365 w/o issue with header setting
- The code to check the opened workbook has a bug. If the workbook (`Header Test`) is opened, but it isn't the first workbook. `WB.Name = wBookName` is evaluated as `False`, then your code `Else:  Workbooks.Open (wFullPathName)` tries to open it again.

Pls try.

```vb
    Dim bExist As Boolean
    For Each WB In Workbooks
        If WB.Name = wBookName Then 'If Header Test workbook is open then make it active.
            WB.Activate
            bExist = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next WB
    If Not bExist Then
        Workbooks.Open (wFullPathName) 'Workbook isn't open so open it.
    End If
```

Comment: I see what I was doing wrong with opening the workbook. Thanks for pointing that out. However, the header problem still exists when I run the code.  If it worked when you tried it, could the problem be something other than the code? Maybe a setting that needs to be changed??

Comment: It's difficult to answer. Please try to create a new workbook named "Header Test.xlsx". Restart Excel and test the code again. Is header problem same if you set header by mannual?

Comment: I deleted the old workbook and created a new one.  I manually made the header "Monday" then saved it.  I shut down all MSOffice then restarted Excel.  I ran the macro and found the header still said "Monday". So, this tells me the header isn't being erased, it's just not being saved.

Comment: Please remove `Workbooks(wBookName).Close` and check the header setting before closing.

Comment: It works up until that point. The header reads "Saturday", like it should, and when I then manually save it, the header is saved as well.  The problem lies with letting the macro save the workbook.  I thought it might be an argument with Workbooks(wBookName).Close but I didn't see any.

Comment: I also tried stepping through the macro and found it works. It doesn't work when I just let it run without interruption.

Comment: Try `Workbooks(wBookName).Save: Workbooks(wBookName).Close` .

Comment: No luck.  I tried it with the workbook already open and also with the workbook closed.